How to prevent ohmyzsh to clear the terminal screen?
I'm using iTerm with ohmyzsh. When I exit a ssh connection it always clears my terminal screen and I find that super annoying. I only experience this behaviour since I have installed ohmyzsh on the connected machine as well, before I used normal bash on that machine. I'm not sure if this comes from iTerm, zsh or ohmyzsh.
Does anyone know how can I prevent my terminal to clear the screen when I'm exiting the ssh session?
I tried to google but don't know what's the problem cause.

Sounds like something enables/disables the alternate screen before/after (respectively) executing ssh, though I don't see where ohmyzsh might do that.

If you execute tput rmcup after exiting ssh, do you get your previous screen contents back?

@chepner: No, still the same behaviour. If I scroll up I can see my previous commands of the other session. But I don't like that the screen get cleared and my cursor jumps up on the first line of my terminal. Instead I would like to exit my session and that my cursor just goes to next line while displaying my previous commands and outputs I made.

The same thing happens to macOS Terminal, too. Terminal is using bash while iTerm is using zsh. I think that the session I am connecting to (also using oh-my-zsh) is causing this problem. When I connect to a session with a bash shell it behaves normal like I used to it.

The solution posted here helped:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70955/preventing-the-screen-from-being-cleared-when-exiting-an-ssh-session
The /etc/zlogout caused the clearance of the screen at logout of the ssh session to a zsh shell.
I fixed it by creating a ~/.zlogout file and add:
alias clear=""

Or:
echo 'alias clear=""' > ~/.zlogout

